# Create Voronoi/Thiessen polygons in QGIS around 3 points

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

Running QGIS 1.8.0

I have three bus compounds.  I would like to generate Voronoi/Thiessen polygons around those three points.  Following Voronoi/Thiessen adding an all school points will allow us to determine which school should be served by which bus compound.

Creating Voronoi:
[image]

It works very quickly and results in:
[image]

Obviously not what I expected.  Can anyone shed some insight?

Thanks

Comment: You have too few points. I tested it with only 3 points and got similar result. Seems that this tool doesn't work correctly with such small amount of points. Maybe you should report it as a bug.

Comment: there is also a bug in the algorithm when using an extent beyond the bounding rectangle of the input points. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/voronoi-polygons-that-run-out-to-infinity?rq=1   An ArcMap version corrects this if you have access to it, I can send the link.