# Can Voronoi/Thiessen polygons be created using ArcObjects without 3D Analyst license?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, voronoi-thiessen

Has any body used ITinNodeCollection to generate Voronoi/Thiessen polygons.
I have a point featureclass for which I want to create Voronoi/Thiessen polygons.

Does this require 3d analyst license?

Comment: Where do you store your data? Do you have access to any spatial SQL functions such as ConvexFull in SQL Server? They can provide a solution which might work well for you.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I want create it in memory using Arcobjects. I can not use third party software nor I could your ArcGIS tools.

Comment: The code that I have written has some issues. Any help on this.

Comment: postITinEdit ptinedit = null ;
                    ptinedit = new TinClass();

                    ptinedit.InitNew (pextent);
                    object Missing = Type.Missing; ptinedit.AddFromFeatureClass(inputLy.FeatureClass, null, null, null, esriTinSurfaceType.esriTinMassPoint, ref Missing); //this is returning empty tin. anything wrong I am doing? Inputly layer is a point feature class.

Comment: //please add this part above the code given in my previous postITinEdit ptinedit = null ;
                    ptinedit = new TinClass();

                    ptinedit.InitNew (pextent);
                    object Missing = Type.Missing;

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [Triangulation tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6e9bc6cbf93d4939b2eb04ff8519be47) which works with any Arc* license level

See this [thread as well](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/voronoi-polygons-that-run-out-to-infinity?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The answer may vary depending on the version of ArcGIS that you are using, but for instance with 10 you need either 3D analyst (for all "TIN" objects ) or an ArcInfo (Advanced) licence (in this case, look for CreateThiessenPolygons) .

The function is also available here http://www.ian-ko.com/

Comment: I do have arcinfo license. However, 3d analyst extension seems to be separate floating license. So, whenever, I need it, it should be requested.

Comment: arcobject with "TIN" all require 3D analyst, but you can use CreateThiessenPolygons with ArcInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted in github a project in arcobjects to create polygons thiessen using arcview license: https://github.com/nicogis/Voronoi

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spatial Analyst but not 3D analyst, we (a university team) created an ArcGIS 10.0 addin that computes regular and weighted Voronoi polygons using a raster methodolgy. The addin itself is free and the code is open source.

https://github.com/UNTGeography/VoronoiDiagramsGIS