# Creating Thiessen Polygons (Analysis) by defining external feature boundary?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vba, voronoi-thiessen

Although this issue has been addressed in this post some months ago: [Thiessen Polygon delineation within a Feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/thiessen-polygon-delineation-within-a-feature), the appropriate answer has not been given. So, new ideas are welcome.

How can we use the Create Thiessen Polygons (Analysis) tool available with ArcInfo license by defining an external feature boundary (e.g. study area boundaries defined by a polygon) for the created thiessen polygons?

As I have seen this is not possible via the Environments...options in that tool.

Is there any available code in VBA for doing this? or How can I run this tool within a VBA code?

The comments indicate that ArcGIS 9.2 and 9.3 is being used, the tag indicates version 10, the first post is for that version not previous ones.