# Digitizing boundaries for the educational office according to its affiliated schools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, digitizing

I have a layer of administrative boundaries, and within these borders, there are a group of separate schools for boys and girls, and these schools are under the supervision of several educational offices. [image]
My goal is to digitize boundaries (Polygon) for the educational office according to its affiliated schools, taking into account the administrative boundaries of the city.
How can I digitize these boundaries correctly given the lack of time
using ArcMap 10.8 or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370630/hard-line-barriers-for-thiessen-polygons/370890#370890